# How to convert 水瀬いのり to %e6%b0%b4%e7%80%ac%e3%81%84%e3%81%ae%e3%82%8a in php?

Tags: php, unicode, decode, encode

i wonder, how to convert character 水瀬いのり to %e6%b0%b4%e7%80%ac%e3%81%84%e3%81%ae%e3%82%8a in php?

also 보이프렌드 to %eb%b3%b4%ec%9d%b4%ed%94%84%eb%a0%8c%eb%93%9c ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This one would help [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php)

See here for an example:

```
$str = '水瀬いのり';
var_dump( urlencode($str) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function for that.

```
echo urlencode('보이프렌드');
// output: %EB%B3%B4%EC%9D%B4%ED%94%84%EB%A0%8C%EB%93%9C
```

If you really need that the result will be in lowercase then you also must to use the [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function.

```
echo strtolower(urlencode('보이프렌드'));
// output: %eb%b3%b4%ec%9d%b4%ed%94%84%eb%a0%8c%eb%93%9c
```